# Copy Excel rows from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: python, excel, anaconda, spyder, openpyxl

I am trying to copy/paste an Excel sheet (csv file) to a different, master Excel sheet. This master sheet already contains data and I would like to append data to it.

However, the code runs without error messages and it does not append any data to the master sheet.

Code below:

```
#from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#file to be copied
wb1 = load_workbook('inputDataTable.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('testthis')

#file to be pasted into
wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('testthis')

def copyRows():
#range counter for rows/cols
    rowCounter = 0
    for row in ws1.iter_rows():
        colCounter = 0
        for col in ws1.iter_cols():
            colCounter += 1
        rowCounter += 1   
#copy part
    rowList = [] #list of lists of rows
    for i in range(1, rowCounter+1):
        rowSelected = [] #list of rows
        for j in range(1, colCounter+1):
            rowSelected.append(ws1.cell(row=i, column=j).value) #cell values are added to the list of rows
        rowList.append(rowSelected)
    print(rowList)
    return rowList



def pasteRows(copiedData):
#range counter for rows/cols
    rowCounter = 0
    for row in ws2.iter_rows():
        colCounter = 0
        for col in ws2.iter_cols():
            colCounter += 1
        rowCounter += 1
#paste part
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(1, rowCounter+1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(1, colCounter+1):
            ws2.cell(row=i, column=j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1
    wb2.save('test.xlsx')
pasteRows(copyRows())
```

Just like [this](https://yagisanatode.com/2017/11/18/copy-and-paste-ranges-in-excel-with-openpyxl-and-python-3/) but without hard-codes ranges.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: what if the second excel file contains some rows. DO you want to append rows or clear old data ans write new one

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over again.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Will edit my post. The point is that I have a master Excel sheet and I want to append data to it from a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the way you calculate and use counter

a rowCounter simply means row in an excel file
suppose you have two files
    inp.xlsx  3 rows
    out.xlsx  2 rows

```
first you calculate __rowCounter__ as 3 in copyrows()
then you calculate again __rowCounter__  in pasterows() 
for file __out.xlsx__ and it becomes 2
```

so you want to write only 2 rows

in case file didn't exist or was empty 
your loop writes 0 times as **rowCounter** becomes 0

try this for counter

```
wb = load_workbook(path, use_iterators=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

rowCounter = sheet.max_row
colCounter = sheet.max_column
```

here is your answer

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

row_counter = ws1.max_row
col_counter = ws1.max_column

#file to be pasted into
wb2 = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')



def copyRows():
# we use global variable row_counter and col_counter directly into pasteRows()
#copy part
    rowList = [] #list of lists of rows
    for i in range(1, row_counter+1):
        rowSelected = [] #list of rows
        for j in range(1, col_counter+1):
            rowSelected.append(ws1.cell(row=i, column=j).value) #cell values are added to the list of rows
        rowList.append(rowSelected)
    print(rowList)
    return rowList



def pasteRows(data):
#paste part
    countRow = ws2.max_row  # in case ws2 contains rows already
    for Row in range(row_counter):
        for Col in range(col_counter):
            ws2.cell(row= Row+countRow + 1, column=Col+1).value = data[Row][Col]

    wb2.save('test.xlsx')
pasteRows(copyRows())


##  the following is the content of each xlsx files
##
##      input.xlsx
##    Name      Class     Marks
##    Roushan    7        90
##    James      8        78
##    Johny      9         95
##
##      output.xlsx
##    we     are   here
##
##     test.xlsx empty
##
##     both input.xlsx and output.xlsx have cells in Sheet1
```

Comment: I understand your explanation, I will try it out. But whenever I use your code I get error

wb1 = load_workbook('inputDataTable.xlsx',use_iterators=True)

Comment: wb1 = load_workbook('inputDataTable.xlsx',use_iterators=True)


I have replaced 'use_iterators' with 'read_only=True' as I read in another post, but then I get the following error message:

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'max_rows'

Right now I am adjusting the code now, I appreciate your input.

Comment: It may give you a deprecation warning that u can cope with by changing wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name) by wb[sheet_name]  @PhantomWebs